# How to dynamically load 1 iframe from other in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

```
<iframe name="main" id="menu" src="menu.aspx" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
<iframe name="main" id="content" src="content.aspx" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
```

I have two `iframe` in my homepage

1. **Menu iframe** (*to load the menu*)
2. **Content iframe** (*to load content page..I am getting redirected into the respective content pages from back end code like this*)

Code:

```
If CType(Session("ID"), String) = Nothing Then
     Main.Attributes.Add("src", "AdvSrch.aspx")
Else ' Querystring contains the ID!
     Main.Attributes.Add("src", "Home.aspx?Id=" & Session("ID").ToString)
End If
```

I want to load a different menu in menu `iframe` from a button click on content `iframe` page

Comment: What is the reason for using an iframe in your application? Why not just use for example two usercontrols?

Comment: This is an old application built some 15 years back and I am not supposed to change any existing functionality